# How do I fix my corrupt video files?

Tags: video

I have multiple video files that have been taken on an iphone, put onto the PC and then deleted off the phone without being tested (yay colleagues!). None of these video files will work and I've tried everything I can think of/find to fix them and nothing has worked. The issue I'm having is that the files seem to have no information, when i click on properties there is no length/resolution/bit rate.

The video properties http://puu.sh/cBvBL/45128864ed.png

The files are all .MOV but no programs seem to recognize them as such, VLC won't play any of them, and none of the repair programs will work as they don't recognize the files as .MOV's. The only success I've had with this issue is on mp4repair.org which has seemed to recognize the file as a video, but only recognizes 2 minutes of footage, when i know that the video is at least 10 minutes long.

Anyone have any ideas? I'm Stumped.

Answer (score 1):

If they are MOVs, the first thing I would do is find a computer with Quicktime correctly installed, to see whether they play on there.  If they do, it could be a codec issue on your machine.  Any Mac with Final Cut installed should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried transcoding them? It worked for me once, although I didn't have the same issues you had. I simply had a. .MOV file that was not being accepted into FCP and I transcoded it which seemed to fix it. I don't know if you'll have any luck since VLC and non of your repair programs will work but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Tried this, no luck, transcoder would just output a 4kb file.